# Background color 50% one color and 50% another color

Tags: css, background, gradient

Inside a div I want to put a background color in the first 50% of it's width, and another color the other 50% of it's width. Ideally On resize I want it to adjust seamlessly without any artifacts or jittery effects.

Ideally I want to avoid using other divs inside the code as I'm working with existing HTML that is difficult to change - really looking for a 100% CSS solution.

**I'm looking for something like this (I mocked this up with Fireworks):**
[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can use something like, but based upong the browsers you have to support, it may not work across all of them.

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff0000 50%, #0000ff 50%);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use :before and :after pseudo elements.

```
#somediv {
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
}

#somediv:after, #somediv:before {
  content:' ';
  position: absolute;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#somediv:after {left: 0px; background: #F00;  }
#somediv:before {right: 0px; background: #00F;}
```

EDIT: like so http://plnkr.co/edit/hm9bHNuuzh2EK4zwn3nr?p=preview

Will even work in ie8 where gradients will not.

let me know if this need to be more tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn8PZ/

```
div {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, tan 50%, green 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, tan 50%, green 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, tan 50%, green 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, tan 50%, green 50%);
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct (best) answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a gradient, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/F3M5e/

Relevant code:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #1e5799 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(100%,#000000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 50%,#000000 50%,#000000 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Edit: horizontal gradient http://jsfiddle.net/F3M5e/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.background{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2897e0 40%, #F1F1F1 40%);
 height:200px;
 
}

.background2{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #2897e0 50%, #28e09c 50%);

 height:200px;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="one">

<div class="background">
</div>
<div class="background2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question

Comment: The question was Inside a div I want to put a background color in the first 50% of its width, and another color the other 50% of its the width. so here i use the property -webkit-linear-gradient(right, color  50%, color 50%) .